# Material UI: I want to make this component responsive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this project and it is in order to monitor employees and I have a component which is "create workspace"

and I have added elements to this interface and I want this interface to be responsive, how can I do that?

And what are the ways in which you can make this page responsive?

Within this component, I have added a group of elements.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

    resize:{
        fontSize:24
    }

});

const Settings: FC = () => {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
            <Card style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent' ,   maxWidth: 1500 , minWidth: 500}}>

                <CardContent>

                    <Box
                        sx={{
                            maxWidth: 1500,
                            // minWidth: 300
                        }}
                    >

                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                display: 'flex',
                                justifyContent: 'start'
                            }}
                        >

                            <Avatar style={{width: '5rem', height: '5rem'}} alt="Remy Sharp"
                                    src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"/>

                            <TextField

                                fullWidth
                                name="workspaceName"
                                placeholder="Workspace Name"
                                variant="standard"
                                style={{
                                    paddingLeft: '1.4rem',
                                    transition: ' all .2s cubic-bezier(.785,.135,.15,.86) 0s',
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    flexGrow: 1,
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    color: '#828588',

                                }}
                                InputProps={{
                                    classes: {
                                        input: classes.resize,
                                    },
                                }}
                                defaultValue="nameeeee"
                            />


                        </Box>

                    </Box>
                    <CardActions
                        style={{ paddingTop: '10rem'}}
                    >

                            <Button style={{
                                minWidth: '10rem',
                                fontSize: '1.5rem',
                                height: '44px',
                                fontWeight: 400,
                                textShadow: 'none',
                                color: '#fd71af',
                                border: 0,
                                background: 'none'

                            }}>Delete Workspace</Button>

                            <Button
                                color="primary"
                                component={RouterLink}
                                to="/dashboard/workspaces/1"
                                variant="contained"
                                style={{
                                    minWidth: '13rem',
                                    minHeight: '4.3rem',
                                    fontSize: '1.4rem',
                                    backgroundColor: '#7b68ee',
                                    borderRadius: 6,
                                    marginLeft:'60rem'

                                }}
                            >
                                Saved
                            </Button>


                    </CardActions>
                </CardContent>

            </Card>
    );
}

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use material UI grids where ever you want to make the layout responsive. Check its documentation here : [Material UI Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)

You can add different layouts for different screen sizes. You should also wrap your component in the [Container](https://material-ui.com/components/container/#container) component provided by Material-UI, It makes your web page fluid.

Hope this answers your question.